AttributeError: 'JsonStoreManager' object has no attribute 'get_instance'
I'm trying to split my kivy app classes into multiple files, but when trying to import the module, I get the error message in the title. Here's the code from the module:
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

class JsonStoreManager:
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = JsonStore("user_info.json")
        return cls._instance

When I try to call the "get_instance" function in my Main file, it says that it isn't an attribute of the class.
This is what I use to call the function in Main:
self.stored_data = JsonStoreManager.get_instance()


Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

how do you import it? Maybe you import wrong file or you have file with the same name but in different place - and it doesn't have get_instance(). If you use import module then you can use print( module.__file__ ) to get /full/path/to/module and you can open  this file to check what is inside.

Running it on my machine it works fine, so I imagine it has something to do with how you're importing the module.
For a file containing the code you gave named json_store_manager.py I imported the module (and called the get_instance() method successfully like this:
import json_store_manager
json_store_manager.JsonStoreManager.get_instance()

And it runs without error (except that I don't have your JsonStore package so that line in get_instance() throws an exception).

I was importing with From "filename" import "classname". Changing it to just import "filename" fixed that error. Thank you!
